# Comment accorder au pluriel les groupes de mots suivants

Tags: accord, pluriel, complément-de-nom

Bonjour!

Je me demande comment accorder correctement des groupes de mots comme les suivants au pluriel?

1. une plage de disponibilité / des plages de disponibilité(s)
2. un gabarit d'horaire / des gabarits d'horaire(s)

Puisqu'il y a présence d'une préposition, je ne crois pas qu'il s'agisse de noms en apposition (noms épithètes), mais j'ai un doute. Devrais-je suivre les règles de [cet article](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4661)?

Comment: Pour le 1. je pense qu'on pourrait avoir disponibilité soit au sing. soit au plur. selon si on recherche un ou plusieurs créneaux de disponibilité. Pour le 2. je laisserais le mot au singulier car je le comprends comme un support unique qui contient une planning, une répartition d'heures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I**
En se rapportant à l'usage actuel on ne devrait utiliser que le singulier dans le cas de « plage de disponibilité » ([ngram 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plage+de+disponibilit%C3%A9%2Cplage+de+disponibilit%C3%A9s&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplage%20de%20disponibilit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cplage%20de%20disponibilit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0)), le pluriel ne se trouve pas. Dans le cas où « plage » est au pluriel, il n'y a pas de différence : on ne trouve que le singulier pour « disponibilité » ([ngram 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plage+de+disponibilit%C3%A9%2Cplage+de+disponibilit%C3%A9s&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplage%20de%20disponibilit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cplage%20de%20disponibilit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0)).

Cela ne signifie pas que tous les cas ont été matérialisés et rapportés dans les textes.  Dans le cas envisagé, où il s'agit de « disponibilité » en tant que nom non comptable il ne faut pas d's (conformément à l'évidence donné par les ngrams). Cependant, à partir de ce mot il est possible de définir dans des contextes assez techniques que les dictionnaires le plus souvent peuvent  ne  pas encore prendre en compte, des concepts comptables (sur le modèle « de la bière / une bière (ration, type de bière) »). Dans un cas comparativement rare tel que celui-ci, il devient logique d'introduire un s, et cela peut être nécessaire aussi bien lorsque « plage » est au singulier. C'est le scripteur/locuteur qui décide selon le sens qui est donné au terme « disponibilité » dans le contexte donné.

**II**
**a/** On ne trouve pas la combinaison « gabarit d'horaire »  ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gabarit+d%27horaire&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=)), ce qui ne signifie pas que, nécessairement, c'est une combinaison que l'on ne peut pas utiliser. La consultation de l'entrée « horaire » dans le TLFi donne ceci (quatre définitions).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/horaire)) (numérotation de user LPH)
> **[1]** A. − Règlement des heures d'une manifestation, d'un service régulier (notamment dans le domaine des transports); p. méton. tableau, livret qui indique ces heures.
> **[2]** B. − Répartition des heures de travail; p. méton. tableau, livret qui les indique.
> **[3]** Réglementation des heures de travail qui permet aux salariés de déterminer eux-mêmes le début et la fin de leur travail et le nombre d'heures de travail de la journée, pourvu qu'un certain total hebdomadaire, fixé à l'avance, soit assuré (Gida 1973). Synon. horaire libre, souple, variable, à la carte.
> **[4]** P. ext. Emploi du temps. Horaire chargé; aménager un horaire.

Laissant de côté « règlement » et « règlementation », on voit, à partir de ces définitions qu'un horaire est un *une répartition, un emploi du temps*. En aucun de ces cas n'est le terme « gabarit », qui signifie essentiellement « dimension »,  un terme qui caractérise ces concepts. On voit aussi que le terme  collocatif  « chargé » dans le cas de « emploi du temps » ne confère pas une idée de taille ou de dimension mais une idée de poids sur ceux qui sont astreints à respecter l'horaire. Rendre cette caractéristique d'un horaire par des expression telles que « son importance », « sa grandeur », « sa taille », etc. ne correspond pas à la nature de cette chose, laquelle est une distribution ; de même, le terme « distribution » (sauf dans le sens informatique) n'est d'habitude pas caractérisé par les notions de taille ou de grandeur. L'idée est plutôt celle d'obligation plus ou moins fréquente. Il est donc difficile de formuler cet aspect d'un horaire. Je considèrerais donc un autre terme, tel que « *l'imposition d'horaire* » (qui n'existe pas pour le moment, mais qui n'est probablement pas la seule solution, ni, possiblement, la meilleure).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/modalit%C3%A9)) **B.** − Action d'obliger à subir ou à faire une chose généralement désagréable, pénible ou difficile.

Malgré la nature assez descriptive de cette combinaison, il faut quand même la définir. L'*imposition d'horaire* serait la charge matérielle et/ou morale que fait peser un horaire sur ceux qui sont tenus de le respecter ou sur ce qui y est soumis, de par la fréquence plus ou moins grande des activités et actions que cet horaire implique.

- Une forte imposition d'horaire → un horaire chargé
- une imposition d'horaire souple → un horaire souple
- une imposition d'horaire forte mais souple → un horaire chargé mais souple

Il semble cependant que l'on puisse toujours s'arranger facilement pour remplacer « gabarit d'horaire …/imposition d'horaire… » par une expression équivalent où « horaire » devient le noyau, ou bien autrement, par une construction copulative où  il est le sujet.

- Le patron ne voulait pas un gabarit d'horaire trop grand pour ses employés.
- Le patron ne voulait pas que ses employés aient un horaire trop chargé.
- Le patron ne voulait pas que l(horaire de ses employés soit trop chargé.

**b/** Bien que cette construction puisse avoir à être rejetée du point de vue sémantique, le rapport grammatical entre les deux mots reste valide. Il s'agit, de façon similaire à ce que l'article cité dans la question avance, d'un rapport de complémentation (« horaire » est le complément du nom « gabarit ») et cela pourrait être rapproché des cas relevant de l'apport de complémentation mentionné dans l'article, mais pas assimilé à ces cas (la relation est différente) ; on peut parler du gabarit en tant que caractéristique telle qu'applicable à l'horaire, non d'un gabarit qui serait aussi un horaire (comme dans l'apport de qualification, que je n'appellerais d'ailleurs  pas qualification mais requalification) ; en prenant l'exemple concret « tailles de chapeau », on voit cela plus nettement.

« Chapeau » qualifie la taille ; c'est un mot qui précise la sorte de taille de quelque chose que l'on peut génériquement considérer par un terme singulier, le chapeau : la taille telle qu'elle est défini en ce qui concerne le chapeau, un chapeau ;  on peut aussi la considérer génériquement par un terme pluriel, les chapeaux : la taille telle qu'elle est défini en ce qui concerne les chapeaux. La logique ne semble pas être une ressource sure pour déterminer ce que l'usage devrait être et avant qu'une convention soit adoptée les deux possibilités peuvent être considérées comme correctes.

Bien que la recherche de l'usage montre que la préférence soit de choisir la simplicité et d'utiliser un singulier lorsque « taille » est au singulier, il existe quelques cas d'utilisation du pluriel. Le nombre des cas augmente de façon importante lorsque le pluriel de « taille » est utilisé, ceci étant dû probablement à une influence subjective causé par la notion  plurielle du premier terme.

> [taille de chapeau](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=taille+de+chapeau) : 41
> [taille de chapeaux](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=taille+de+chapeaux) : 5
> [tailles de chapeau](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=tailles+de+chapeau) : 17
> [tailles de chapeaux](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=tailles+de+chapeaux) : 9

En conclusion, je dirais qu'il n'y a pas de raison suffisante pour utiliser un s, dans tous les cas.

---

*Additions en conséquence de précisions supplémentaires (voir premier commentaire à cette réponse)*

Une extension de la recherche à tout le texte analysé par Google on obtient les résultats suivants.

[gabarit d'horaire](https://www.bing.com/search?q=gabarit+d%27horaire&form=ANNTH1&refig=3e21435e448b4ba7a56c4879fa990668) : 2
[gabarit d'horaires](https://www.bing.com/search?q=gabarit+d%27horaires&form=ANNTH1&refig=f7f20ef49f9e4ff594dd319cfe834671) : 0
[gabarits d'horaire](https://www.bing.com/search?q=gabarits+d%27horaire&form=ANNTH1&refig=9c9fc97caddb4b39b8416ed2714acf75) :  0
[gabarits d'horaires](https://www.bing.com/search?q=gabarits+d%27horaires&form=ANNTH1&refig=1c0bb456e2f448e788d23c2afe3a055b) : 0

Tout cela est plutôt maigre pour pouvoir se faire une idée, mis à part la confirmation de l'existence de ce concept. On trouve cependant un cas de « gabarits de plages horaires » (chez Agendrix, répété quatre fois). On peut assimiler « horaire » à « plage horaire », il me semble, et le raisonnement dans la première partie de ma réponse est le même : même s'il est question de plusieurs plages, le mot « gabarit » est spécialisé à une sorte de chose qui est la plage horaire en tant qu'entité générique, et le pluriel n'apporte rien (à mon avis).

Comme ce terme est proche du mot « type » et qu'un plus grand nombre de cas d'utilisation occurrent pour « type(s) d'horaire(s) », on peut essayer de voir ce qu'est l'usage concernant cette combinaison.

[type d'horaire](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=type+d%27horaire) : 13
[type d'horaires](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=type+d%27horaires) : 8
[types d'horaire](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=types+d%27horaire) : 1
[types d'horaires](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=types+d%27horaires) : 9

Ce résultat reflète plus ou moins la conclusion que le pluriel n'est pas significatif et qu'il existe une influence subjective à utiliser le pluriel du second terme lorsque le pluriel est utilisé pour le premier.
Le changement du sens de « gabarit » ne semble donc pas changer la conclusion dans la première partie de ma réponse.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour cette réponse élaborée au-delà de mes espérances! J'apprécie vos liens vers ngram, outil que je ne connaissais pas. Ceci dit, je dois préciser que, dans le cas de "gabarit d'horaire", "gabarit" est utilisé dans le sens de "modèle", "patron" et non de "dimension". Dans le contexte de mon projet, un gabarit d'horaire est un modèle qui sert à remplir rapidement l'emploi du temps d'un professionnel, celui-ci étant semblable de semaine en semaine. Cela influencerait-il votre réponse? Merci!

Comment: @JGL Comme l'espace des commentaires ne se prête  pas à cette sorte de discussion, j'ai fait une addition à ma réponse